# Problem in trying to solve a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I'm trying to solve a differential equation but not getting a solution.

Some references I read gave me hits about using a runge kutta method. 
I'm new to the software, any hints regarding this error or how to solve?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message is telling you didn't give any initial conditions in your `NDSolve` expression.

Answer (score 4):

The $\theta(t-\Delta)$ makes it a [Delay Differential Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation), which the [documentation here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDelayDifferentialEquations.html) shows how to solve. You have to specify a history function like this:

```
u[t /; t <= 0] == f[t]
```

For example:

```
NDSolve[{u''[t] + u[t - 1] == 0, 
    u[t /; t <= 0] == 1},
    u, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[u[t] /. First[%], {t, 0, 10}]
```